# move, copy files without using too much memory

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu and
want to move or copy big files.

but as I am using a server with other people, I don't want to possess all the memory and make other processes almost stop.

so is there any way to move or copy files with the memory usage limited?

Comment: This question may be better suited on other sites like [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough disk space,
You can use `split` and `cat` commands.
Use split command to split your big file into small enough parts, move parts to destination,and then use cat command to append parts together.